# Issue in abstracting common code using function interface

Tags: java, java-8

here I have implemented two following functions like below:

```
  Output1 computeFirst(Input1 input) {
        String lockName = input.getId();
        LockItem lockItem = acquireLock(lockName);

        try{

        #critical section

        }catch(Exception e){
              log.error(e);
        }finally{
          releaseLock(lockItem);
        }
  }




  Output2 computeSecond(Input2 input) {
        String lockName = input.getId();
        LockItem lockItem = acquireLock(lockName);

        try{

        #critical section

        }catch(Exception e){
              log.error(e);
        }finally{
          releaseLock(lockItem);
        }
    }
```

These two above functions get called in different flow.

From above two functions I want to abstract out the acquireLock and releaseLock functionality by writing one more function like below:

```
executeWithLock(String lockName, funcionReference) {
   String lockName = input.getId();
   LockItem lockItem = acquireLock(lockName);
   try{
        func.apply
   } catch(Exception e){
        log.error(e);
   } finally {
         releaseLock(lockItem);

   }
}
```

I am not able to figure out how would I implement this executeWithLock function, in that context I have gone through related posts in stackoverflow regarding how to pass function as argument, but could not understand much.

Comment: Just use Runnable?

Comment: Could you please update the question and add the return type of the method "executeWithLock"?

Comment: @TheApprentice executeWithLock should be generic to accomodate multiple functions as mentioned above , that's why I did not mention any return type specifically.

Comment: @Joy I assumed it returned void. In this case, don't use my Runnable solution. If it returns a generic consider adding a "T" as return type and a comment saying that "T" can be either "Output1" or "Output2".

Answer (score 0):

Runnable would not work as there is an output as well.

```
public interface Identifiable{
    String getId();
}

public static <T extends Identifiable,R> R executeWithLock(T input, Function<T,R> func) {
    String lockName = input.getId();
    LockItem lockItem = acquireLock(lockName);
    try{
        return func.apply(input);
    } catch(Exception e){
        log.error(e);
        return null;
    } finally {
        releaseLock(lockItem);
    }
}
```

call like

```
Output1 output = executeWithLock(input1, 
    (input) -> {return /*compute output as in critical section*/ null;});
```

Comment: Hi @gagan-singh, so as per the code in question I can put like this:

  Output1 output = executeWithLock(input1, 
    (input) -> {return computeFirst(input);});

please correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: @Joy you need to remove all the lock code from computeFirst as that is now part of the executewithlock. Only the critical section should remain which should convert input to output.

Comment: @gagansingh because T is generic `input.getId()` can not be resolved, either add a `lockName` parameter to the method signature or let T extend some interface which declared the `getId`-method.

Comment: @gagansingh I have written as follows:


Input1 input1 = Input1.builder.name("test").build();
Output1 output = executeWithLock(input1, 
    (item) -> {return computeFirst((Input1)item);});


It is giving error as:  The method executeWithLock(T, Function<T,R>) in the type  is not applicable for the arguments (Input1, (<no type> item) -> {})

Comment: where did this builder come from? note that Input1 implements an iterface to get the value of id.

Comment: Yeah you are right @gagansingh. But can you please help me the fix the above mentioned compilation issue?

Comment: I mean in case Input1 and Input2 does not implement any interface and I just pass lockname as argument separately then how would I handle the invocation.

Comment: can you put a sample of your critical section? otherwise we are just going in a loop, not knowing what you intend to do.