# Exception handling in Function interface

Tags: java, java-8

I am new to Function interface in Java 8. This question is related to [Issue in abstracting common code using function interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157631/issue-in-abstracting-common-code-using-function-interface). Getting idea from this I have written like below:

```
  public void act(Input1 input) throws NonRetriableException, InvalidInputException {

    Function<UpdateTaskInput, Boolean> func = item -> {
        try {
            activityManager.update(item);
            return true;
        } catch (InterruptedException | JSONException e) {

            throw new NonRetriableException(e);
        } catch (LockUnavailableException e) {

            throw new NonRetriableException(e);
        }
    };

    try {
        lockManager.executeWithLock(input.getTaskID(), input, func);
    } catch (LockUnavailableException e) {
        log.error("{}",e);
        throw new NonRetriableException(e);
    }
   }
```

and:

```
 public void perform()
    throws AutoAllocationException {

     Function<UpdateTaskInput, Boolean> func = item -> {
        try {
            activityManager.allocateTask(item);
            return true;
        } catch (AutoAllocationException ex) {
            log.error("{}",ex);
        }
        return false;
    };

    try {
        lockManager.executeWithLock(input.getTaskID(), input, func);
    } catch (LockUnavailableException e) {
        log.error("{}",e);
    }
  }
```

executeWithLock() in LockManager is as follows:

```
 @Override
 public <T,R> R executeWithLock(String lockName, T input, Function<T,R> func) throws LockUnavailableException {
    LockItem lockItem = acquireLock(lockName);
    R output = func.apply(input);
    releaseLock(lockItem); 
    return output;
}
```

Now my question is:

In `executeWithLock()` function do I have to capture all the exceptions, I mean should I handle exception from `func.apply()`. I want to know this because, `releaseLock` call I should do always irrespective of the fact exception has occurred or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `act` throws an exception your `LockItem lockItem` will not be released in `executeWithLock`. Therefore it is [recommended](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html) to used the try-finally statement when working with `Lock`s:

```
public <T, R> R executeWithLock(String lockName, T input, Function<T, R> func) throws LockUnavailableException {
    LockItem lockItem = acquireLock(lockName);
    try  {
        R output = func.apply(input);
        return output;
    } finally {
        releaseLock(lockItem);
    }
}
```

Another point:
Since `act` is throwing a `NonRetriableException` in a `Function` which does not declare any `Exception` that implies `NonRetriableException extends RuntimeException`. But the following try-catch-block does only catch exceptions of type `LockUnavailableException`. Exceptions of type `NonRetriableException` will not be catched and therefore not handled (logged). They will be propagated to the caller of `act` which is `executeWithLock`. This shows again the significance of the first point.

Comment: I have one more question related to that, I will post a different question.