# Issue in wrapping input in Function interface

Tags: java, java-8

This question is related to [Issue in abstracting common code using function interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157631/issue-in-abstracting-common-code-using-function-interface) and [Exception handling in Function interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51167567/exception-handling-in-function-interface). Getting idea from those I have written like below:

```
  public void act(Input1 input) throws NonRetriableException, InvalidInputException {

    Function<UpdateTaskInput, Boolean> func = item -> {
        try {
            activityManager.update(item);
            return true;
        } catch (InterruptedException | JSONException e) {

            throw new NonRetriableException(e);
        } catch (LockUnavailableException e) {

            throw new NonRetriableException(e);
        }
    };

    try {
        lockManager.executeWithLock(input.getTaskID(), input, func);
    } catch (LockUnavailableException e) {
        log.error("{}",e);
        throw new NonRetriableException(e);
    }
   }
```

and:

```
 public void perform()
    throws AutoAllocationException {

     Function<UpdateTaskInput, Boolean> func = item -> {
        try {
            activityManager.allocateTask(item);
            return true;
        } catch (AutoAllocationException ex) {
            log.error("{}",ex);
        }
        return false;
    };

    try {
        lockManager.executeWithLock(input.getTaskID(), input, func);
    } catch (LockUnavailableException e) {
        log.error("{}",e);
    }
  }
```

executeWithLock() in LockManager is as follows:

```
 @Override
 public <T,R> R executeWithLock(String lockName, T input, Function<T,R> func) throws LockUnavailableException {
    LockItem lockItem = acquireLock(lockName);
   try  {
      R output = func.apply(input);
      return output;
   } finally {
      releaseLock(lockItem);
   }
  }
```

Now the issue with the executeWithLock() function is, it always expects input as an argument, I cannot invoke this for any other function which does not have any input like doStuff().

But I would like to do it using Function interface only with something like following ( so you can see, T is omitted).

```
    @Override
 public <R> R executeWithLock(String lockName, Function<R> func) throws LockUnavailableException {
    LockItem lockItem = acquireLock(lockName);
   try  {
      R output = func.apply(input);
      return output;
   } finally {
      releaseLock(lockItem);
   }
  }
```

Is there any way to do that with Function interface?

Comment: What’s stopping you from using, e.g. `SomeType result = executeWithLock(someID, null, ignored -> doStuff());`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a intermediate helper method, which accepts a [`Supplier<R>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) but no `input`. Which then creates a `Function<?, R>` and delegates to the other method:

```
public <R> R executeWithLock(String lockName, Supplier<R> supplier) throws LockUnavailableException{
    return executeWithLock(
        lockName, 
        null,                     // input is ignored by our function
        ignored -> supplier.get() // this lambda will create Function<?, R> from the Supplier<R>
    );
}
```

This could then be used like this:

```
executeWithLock("mylock", () -> "Some Value");
```

Whereas `() -> "Some Value"` is a `Supplier<String>`.

---

If you can't change that code, and thus not be able to add a intermediate helper method. You might just want to pass `null` as an argument, and then ignore it in the lambda:

```
executeWithLock("myLock", null, ignored -> doStuff());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two methods. The first should take a `Supplier` rather than a `Function` and the input. Using `Supplier` is preferable because it gives you the flexibility to use zero or more input arguments. Using `Function` means you are limited to one.

You also need a second method which uses `Runnable` which supports zero or more input arguments and a void return:

```
public static <R> R executeWithLock(String lockName, Supplier<R> func) {
    Lock lockItem = acquireLock(lockName);
    try  {
        return func.get();
    } finally {
        releaseLock(lockItem);
    }
}

public static void executeWithLock(String lockName, Runnable func) {
    Lock lockItem = acquireLock(lockName);
    try  {
        func.run();
    } finally {
        releaseLock(lockItem);
    }
}
```

Sample usage for these example methods:

```
private static String foo(String input) { return input; }
private static void bar(String input)   { }
```

would look like:

```
String ret = executeWithLock("lockName", () -> foo("someInput"));
executeWithLock("lockName", () -> bar("someInput")); // void return
```

Java is able to infer which version of `executeWithLock` is required based on whether or not there's a return type. If you wanted to be explicit, you could give the methods different names.